# Migrating android app to hosted parse server

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm migrating my android app from Parse android sdk 1.8.1 to 1.13.0. So i can point my app to my hosted Parse server but when i replace the old Parse-1.8.1 to new Parse-1.13.0 library and update the server details in the app. App crash as soon as i run it.

When app crash it shows me below error message in log

```
03-31 13:55:37.196    2247-2247/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.name.appname, PID: 2247
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bolts.TaskCompletionSource
        at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils.callbackOnMainThreadAsync(ParseTaskUtils.java:100)
        at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils.callbackOnMainThreadAsync(ParseTaskUtils.java:87)
        at com.parse.ParseQuery.findInBackground(ParseQuery.java:1211)
        at com.ccna.practicequiz.QuizApplication.onCreate(QuizApplication.java:80)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4344)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.13.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.1.4.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
}
```

Changes in the app to point app to hosted server

```
  //Parse.initialize(this, "<key>", "<key>");
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId("appid")
            .clientKey("<random key>")
            .server("http://192.168.1.177:1337/parse/")   // '/' important after 'parse'
            .build());
```

App is working fine if i use the old Parse-1.8.1 library.I already tried cleaning jar by doing 'gradlew clean jarRelease' and 'gradlew clean testDebug' files still no luck

Comment: try to use SDK 1.13 and still use parse.com, If you will successfully connect you can go and debug your own parse server... this seems you got problem with the SDK implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to update your JAR files, but why use JAR files when you could just grab the dependencies with Gradle?

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
}
```

Also, Play Services is currently `8.4.0` and unless you actually need **all** the Play Services, then it is [recommended to just pick the dependencies](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split) you really use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade bolts-android-1.1.4.jar to the latest version: 1.4.0